# SceneKit, manually control skeleton from skinner

Tags: swift, scenekit

Apple have demo with control 3d robot with 3d pose estimation. Everything connects together and works like magic. No `SceneKit` used.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/capturing_body_motion_in_3d

I'm trying control same robot manually in `SceneKit`. Come up with inconvenient approach:

```
let rightHand = skeleton?.childNode(withName: "right_hand_joint", recursively: true)
rightHand?.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, .pi / 2.0)
rightHand?.parent?.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, .pi / 2.0)
```

[image: 3D Skeleton]

Is there some other approach, where I can set location of the joints and it will automatically calculates angles for skeleton? All other example that I found loads some animations from `.dae` files.